# How do I resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: during Azure Blob Storage initialization

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage

I am getting this `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.azure.sto rage.blob.implementation.util.ModelHelper` when trying to initilalize Azure Blob like this

```
StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_KEY);
BlobServiceClient storageClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().endpoint(endpoint).credential(credential).buildClient();
```

How to solve this?

```
2022-10-28 12:03:30,802 ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServl
et] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.azure.sto
rage.blob.implementation.util.ModelHelper] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.azure.storage.blob.implementation.util.ModelHelper
        at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobUrlParts.parse(BlobUrlParts.java:371) ~[azure-storage-blob-12.20.0.jar!/:12.20.0]
        at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder.endpoint(BlobServiceClientBuilder.java:171) ~[azure-storage-blob-12.20.0.jar!/:12.20.0]
```

My pom.xml has these dependencies

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-storage-blob -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
            <version>12.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Needed to avoid java.lang.ClassNotFoundException-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.33.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I also see a similar failure but with a different error message sometimes

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94) ~[data-pipeline-automation-1.0.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at com.azure.core.implementation.jackson.ObjectMapperShim.createHeaderMapper(ObjectMapperShim.java:135) ~[azure-core-1.33.0.jar!/:1.33.0]
    at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.<init>(JacksonAdapter.java:80) ~[azure-core-1.33.0.jar!/:1.33.0]
    at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.<init>(JacksonAdapter.java:58) ~[azure-core-1.33.0.jar!/:1.33.0]
    at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter$SerializerAdapterHolder.<clinit>(JacksonAdapter.java:112) ~[azure-core-1.33.0.jar!/:1.33.0]
    at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.createDefaultSerializerAdapter(JacksonAdapter.java:121) ~[azure-core-1.33.0.jar!/:1.33.0]
    at com.azure.storage.blob.implementation.util.ModelHelper.<clinit>(ModelHelper.java:61) ~[azure-storage-blob-12.20.0.jar!/:12.20.0]
    at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobUrlParts.parse(BlobUrlParts.java:371) ~[azure-storage-blob-12.20.0.jar!/:12.20.0]
    at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder.endpoint(BlobServiceClientBuilder.java:171) ~[azure-storage-blob-12.20.0.jar!/:12.20.0]
```

Comment: I was able to resolve by simply updating the Azure libs (updated mine to azure-storage-file-datalake 12.15.0...) The problem with me was propably with 'jackson-dataformat-xml' conflict.

Answer (score 0):

- Here, was able to use `blobserviceclient` to create a container in storage using the following code.

```
DefaultAzureCredential k = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build();
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()  
        .endpoint("https://<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/")  
        .credential(k)  
        .buildClient();
```

dependencies:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-storage-blob -->  
<dependency>  
 <groupId>com.azure</groupId>  
 <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>  
 <version>12.20.0</version>  
</dependency>  
  
  
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-core -->  
<dependency>  
 <groupId>com.azure</groupId>  
 <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>  
 <version>1.33.0</version>  
</dependency>  
  
  
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-identity -->  
<dependency>  
 <groupId>com.azure</groupId>  
 <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>  
 <version>1.7.0-beta.2</version>  
 <scope>compile</scope>  
</dependency>
```

[image]

- Now let's come to the `NoClassDefFoundError` error, well you get this error when the JVM is calling a class and not being able to find it at run time.
- Maybe the `ModelHelper`  and the `MapperBuilder` class/dependency are not at the same location as everyone else. What you can do is uninstall everything and then reinstall everything.  Then recompile the project.

Refer this [article](https://rollbar.com/blog/java-no-class-def-found-error/) on `NoClassDefFoundError` by Rollbar

Comment: Thanks for the response @MohitGanorkar. I have similar implementation and I still see the issue in my BlobClient.